# Cassel's book on Elliptic Curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, p-adic-number-theory

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}_p$ be an elliptic curve. Then for $n \geq 1$, let $E_n(\mathbb{Q}) = \left\{P \in E(\mathbb{Q}_p) : \dfrac{x(P)}{y(P)} \in p^n \mathbb{Z}_p\right\}$. According to Cassels in *Lectures on Elliptic Curves*, if $P=(x,y) \in E_1(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ and we set $u(P) = x/y$ then $|u(sx)|_p = |s|_p |u(x)|_p$ where $s$ is an integer.

Why is this the case? I don't understand his "proof". This follows the lemma which states that $|u(x_1 + x_2) - u(x_1) - u(x_2)| \leq \max\{|u(x_1)|^5, |u(x_2)|^5\}$  for $x_1,x_2 \in E_1(\mathbb{Q}_p)$.

Comment: I don’t own Cassels’s book, and am not in a position to find one in a library. Would you accept an argument (undoubtedly different from Cassels’s) based on the formal group of the elliptic curve in question?

Comment: @Lubin Sorry, I would not. I would like to avoid any fancy proofs. Cassels' says that this theorem follows by induction, using the lemma that proceeds it (as stated in the question). My question is: how does it follow by induction? He says it like it's obvious, so I'd like to know what he's thinking. Then again, he leaves out *lots* of steps all over the book.

Comment: I understand your position. Couldn’t you just prove it for two special cases: when $s$ is prime to $p$, so that the abs. val. in question is unchanged, and when $s=p$?